# Auto Open used to execute another macro with VBA

Tags: excel, scheduled-tasks, vba

I have an excel book titled `Can Opener` that is opened by my task scheduler.  It opens another workbook on a shared drive that my task scheduler cannot access, and then closes itself..  `Can Opener` works fine.  The problem I am having is that the other workbook has code that, upon open, if it is 7pm system time executes an update macro to get new data from the servers.  Once this is done the file saves and closes.  The data workbook opens, but no update is occurring, and it does not automatically save and close.  I have tied breaking the code down so it would at least update, and this is not working either.  I have checked several forums and other locations and I still cannot figure out what the problem is.  Can I get a little help?

```
    Sub DataBook_Open()

Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

   If Hour(Now) = 7 And Weekday(Now, vbSunday) < 7 Then

       Run_Update

            Me.Save

            Application.Quit

    Else:   Me.Save
            Application.Quit

   End If



End Sub
```

`Run_Update` is the name of the macro in my module that merely executes that other macros in the module that create the server connection and run the SQL's.  This works fine if manually ran, or run with a button, so I know the error is not here.  Also I am trying to run this code every night at 7pm.

I really appreciate any help I can get guys.

Comment: This code looks like it executes at 7am system time. If you remove or comment out the `If ... Else ... End If` and just have it `Run_Update Me.Save Application.Quit` what happens?

Comment: as @DavidZemens said, for 7pm your hour(now) should equal 19

Comment: I did comment that out last night and it still did not execute the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure DataBook_Open() executes at all?
It might not unless you're calling it from Auto_Open() or Workbook_Open().

Try this minimal test files. Replacing the paths with your actual folders.

--can_opener.xlsm--

```
Sub OpenOtherWorkbook()

  Dim sWbkPath As String
  sWbkPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test_data.xlsm"

  Dim wbkData As Workbook
  Set wbkData = Workbooks.Open(sWbkPath)

End Sub
```

--test_data.xlsm-- in the ThisWorkbook Object

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  If Hour(Now) = 9 Then 'replace with your condition
      UpdateData
      ThisWorkbook.Save
      DoEvents
  Else
      DoEvents
  End If

  ThisWorkbook.Close
  'Application.Quit

End Sub

Sub UpdateData()

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd:hh\hmm")

End Sub
```

Comment: I used your portion of the Workbook_Open sub in my data book, appears to work perfectly now.  I really appreciate the help